# Bind key to a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to bind a key (now without function) to a bash script that I have made on Ubuntu. I'm using a clevo W150HNM/Sager NP5160

I want to use button 1 or 4 for this. (see [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUeYO.jpg)) I don't get any output from `xev`, `getscancodes` or `cat /dev/input/eventX` when pressing this key.

How can I use this key to run the script?

Comment: crossposting: http://askubuntu.com/q/36098/10068

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that some or all of those keys are bound directly in the BIOS and do not generate keycodes and thus will not be bindable. Particularly button 1 might not be reachable, but the other hotkey buttons are likely software readable.

You may need to load a special kernel module specific to that brand laptop or even that model that knows how to listen for and process those keys.